# Fastest method to generate search suggestion list in javascript

Tags: javascript, sql-server, web-services, cloud

> A input box for type=text, which provide a search suggestion.

The point is all available suggestion is on my **sql-server** db.

It will cost few seconds if I simply use ajax to input the search text to server and get the result back. Like entering 'a', it takes 3 seconds to get a list of name with 'a', and then enter 'b', it takes another 3 seconds to get a list of name with 'ab'.

This is not ideal, and thus I use the memcache function of google cloud platform 
(GCP) to save all the name on cloud temporarily.

However, as I have few table to do this, and there will be >400mb data, the memcache missing rate is pretty high and almost hit the limit. So, I want to know more idea about how to do this in faster and more accurate way.

Any idea using any library/ cloud platform(AWS/GCP) are welcome, but I do prefer some methods not using any of these. Just provide idea and some ref (if have) is pretty enough.

Bests and thanks.

Comment: Which language are you using in the backend? In Java you have Apache Lucene to do this: https://lucene.apache.org/core/ which creates some files in your server with the indexes cached and you query through it, in other languages there might be something similar if you cannot find any cloud base solution

Comment: @A.Llorente I can use node.js or python, but I will take a look on site you provided. Thx